# Is there a pthreads API that identifies the handle of a mutex owner?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Is there a pthreads API that identifies the handle of a mutex owner?  I would rather use the pthread API instead of build my own structure and lock/unlock API on the pthreads API.  I am using the C implementation of the pthreads library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any API for this, however, it can be done quite easily.
What you need to do is create a global variable which will hold the pthread handle holding the mutex.
Every time a thread locks the mutex, it set this variable(while the mutex is locked) to `pthread_self()`.

This way, if a mutex is locked, you can easily look at the global variable to see who locked it.

Comment: I am aware of this solution.  I want to leverage as much of the ptheads API as I can.  That is why I ask for a pthreads API that supplies this particular service.  Thanks!